# Accessing other resources created by the same for_each set

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create an az ad app and credential for each entry in a locals set.

The objects in the locals set have values that are needed for both resources, but my issue is the credentials resource needs values from both the locals object as well as the ad application.

This would be easy normally, but I am using a for_each which is complicated, and the value of `each` for the credential resource is the ad application. Is there any way I can get access to the `each` of az app resource but from the credential resource?

```
locals {
  github_repos_with_apps = {
    tftesting_testing = {
      repo        = "tftesting-testing"
      environment = "tfplan"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_application" "aadapp" {
  for_each     = local.github_repos_with_apps
  display_name = join("-", ["github-actions", each.value.repo, each.value.environment])
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]  
}

resource "azuread_application_federated_identity_credential" "cred" {
  for_each              = azuread_application.aadapp
  application_object_id = each.value.object_id
  display_name          = "my-repo-deploy"
  description           = "Deployments for my-repo"
  audiences             = ["api://AzureADTokenExchange"]
  issuer                = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
  subject               = "repo:my-org/${each.value.<something?>.repo}:environment:${each.value.<something?>.environment}"
}
```

In the snippet above I need the `cred` resource to access `aadapp.object_id` but also reference the locals value in order to get `rep` and `environment`. Since both cred and aadapp both use for_each the meaning of `each.value` changes. I'd like to reference the `each.value` of `aadapp` *from* `cred`.

My problem line is the `subject` value in the `cred` resource:

```
subject               = "repo:my-org/${each.value.<something?>.repo}:environment:${each.value.<something?>.environment}"
```

I think I may have to use modules to accomplish this, but I feel there is a quicker way, like being able to store a temporary value on `aadapp` that would let me reference it.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I've updated the description. The `subject` value in `cred` shows what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

After scouring some examples I did find out how to achieve this.

If I change all resources to use `for_each = local.github_repos_with_apps`, I can then use 'each.key` as a lookup to get the other associated resources like so:

```
application_object_id = resource.azuread_application.aadapp[each.key].object_id
```

This allows the `cred` resource to reference the locals values directly

```
subject = "repo:my-org/${each.value.repo}:environment:${each.value.environment}"
```

Full code:

```
locals {
  github_repos_with_apps = {
    first_test : {
      repo        = "tftesting-testing"
      environment = "tfplan"
    }
    second_test : {
      repo        = "bleep-testing"
      environment = "tfplan"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_application" "aadapp" {
  for_each     = local.github_repos_with_apps
  display_name = join("-", ["github-actions", each.value.repo, each.value.environment])
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      required_resource_access
    ]
  }
}

resource "azuread_application_federated_identity_credential" "cred" {
  for_each              = local.github_repos_with_apps
  application_object_id = resource.azuread_application.aadapp[each.key].object_id
  display_name          = each.value.repo
  description           = "Deployments for my-repo"
  audiences             = ["api://AzureADTokenExchange"]
  issuer                = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
  subject               = "repo:my-org/${each.value.repo}:environment:${each.value.environment}"
}
```